# iOS keyboard issue - Keyboard not closed when click Done or when click update button

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard, xcode7.2, ios9.2

I'm building an .api file for iOS app that is made with Xcode 7.2, i have two fields in my page - email and phone. When i try to edit the email or phone in textfield the keyboard appears.

Handle to hide keyboard in

1. keyboard Done button
2. Update button
3. Textfield added over the UIControl, handle on TouchDown Event.

with code `[self.view endEditing:TRUE];` but can't able to hide the keyboard.

**Issue Occurs only when build .api file and launch.. if i debug the same version of code, its works fine - keyboard hidden when click done or when click over the view..**

Any help is welcome..

Thanks!

[image: Keyboard not closed when click Done or when click update button]

Comment: make sure delegates are attached to those textfields...

Comment: 1) CODELESS, Zero Line Of Code.

2) Works Automatically

3) No More UIScrollView

4) No More Subclasses

5) No More Manual Work

6) No More #imports http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/846002/Codeless-IQKeyboardManager-for-iOS

Comment: yes.. delegates added for the textfields.. Its works when i debug from xcode but when i build .ipa the issue occurs.. @Fahim Parkar

Comment: Thanks for sample,its good.. but its not resolve my issue.. @iOSDeveloper

Comment: does the ipa works on iphone without an issue ? @Prasath

Comment: @Mr.T yes.. its working good, only this keyboard issue

Comment: Keyboard issue - because of UIControl in ViewController..

Whole UI added under UIControl and Email,Phone Textfield added under scrollview(TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView), in UIControl OnTouchdown action keyboard hidden handled..

now removed the UIControl outlet,actions and class in UI.. keyboard hidden handled with Touch Gestures..

now keyboard hidden in all cases.. its working fine, when build ipa or when we debug..

The issue resolved..

Thanks all for ur support...

Answer (score 0):

Implement the delegate method

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.yourIBtextField.delegate = self;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField 
{
[textField resignFirstResponder];
return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keyboard issue - because of UIControl in ViewController..

Whole UI added under UIControl and Email,Phone Textfield added under scrollview(TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView),
in UIControl OnTouchdown action keyboard hidden handled..

now removed the UIControl outlet,actions and class in UI.. 
keyboard hidden handled with Touch Gestures..

now keyboard hidden in all cases.. its working fine, when build ipa or when debug..

The issue resolved..

Answer (score 0):

1. For keyboard done button: Implement the delegate method

   ```
   - (void) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField)textField
   {
       [self.emailTF resignFirstResponder];
       [self.phoneTF resignFirstResponder];

   }
   ```
2. For update Button: Implement the method

   ```
   - (void)updateButtonClick:(UIButton *)button
   {

      /the code you want to write.../

      [self.emailTF resignFirstResponder];
      [self.phoneTF resignFirstResponder];

   }
   ```
3. For touch self.view to return keyBoard: Implement the method

   ```
   - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
   {

      [self.emailTF resignFirstResponder];
      [self.phoneTF resignFirstResponder];  

   }
   ```

Hope that this answer can help you :)